# Idiom/phrase for; something so explosively life changing/profound that it leaves you speechless

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

I found a few that came kind of close but I'm looking for something tht essentially combines the definitions of Epochal Momentum, Red/Scarlett Letter, & Magnum Opus. But it has a lot more of a dramatic and/or powerful punch to it. Think like you saw the best movie of your life and you have no words for it but are filled to the brim with powerful and happy emotions.  I know it may seem silly or be basic knowledge and I'm just over thinking it. But I've legit been searching for like an hour for it; as I'm using it in this book project I'm test running. And I want to have as much expanded grammatical terms as possible.

Comment: The body of the question doesn't quite jibe with the title. Something which is profound or life-changing isn't necessarily the same as something which makes you happy. Could you make yourself clearer, please? And what's with this _Scarlet Letter_? I thought it was just the title of a Hawthorne novel. :)

Comment: yeah I can see the confusion, and I just read somewhere that Scarlett Letter was a idiom for something really important as it goes back to the biblical age when people would mark church days with red. But when I said life changing I meant in a positive sense like marriage, childbirth, etc. I sometimes forget phrases can have more vague emotions. But my intent all along was a positively represented type of life changing as the fore mentioned things above. I hope this clears things up

Comment: I have added an answer. It seems to be what you're after.

Comment: OP means **Red Letter Day**.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest **rite of passage**, which *Merriam-Webster* defines as:

> **a ritual, event, or experience that marks or constitutes a major milestone or change in a person's life**

*Rites of passage celebrate the social movement of individuals into and out of groups or into or out of statuses of critical importance to the individual and to the community. Reproduction, the achievement of manhood and womanhood, marriage, and death are the principal worldwide occasions for rites of passage.*

[Marvin Harris]

For the more individual aspect (as opposed to the social one implied in "rite of passage", you could consider a **Road to Damascus** experience, referencing the [biblical account](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts%209&version=NIV) of [Paul the Apostle's conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_of_Paul_the_Apostle).

Comment: That's a great suggestion I might actually use that one further into the book but not quite the one I'm currently looking for. The "major milestone" part is good but less "ritualistic" as the definition describes

Comment: _turning point_? _road to Damascus_? Something along these lines?

Comment: Yeah that's it! I forgot about road to Damascus that's about spot on.

Comment: I've edited "Road to Damascus" into your answer, because I came here to answer just that, but you'd already given it in a comment...

Comment: @Conrado Thanks for the edit. That's what instantly occured to me on seeing the question, but then I thought the OP wasn't exactly looking for this—(*...But when I said life changing I meant in a positive sense like marriage, childbirth, etc....*)—, so I went with *rite of passage*.

Answer (score 0):

**a bolt from the blue** (idiom)

> *idiom* (also **a bolt out of the blue**)
>
> Something important or unusual that happens suddenly or unexpectedly:
>
> *The resignation of the chairman came like a bolt from the blue.*
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/bolt-from-the-blue)

> *Less commonly* **bolt out of the blue**
>
> A complete surprise : something totally unexpected
>
> The first known use of bolt from the blue was in 1856.
> [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bolt%20from%20the%20blue)

> **A bolt from (or out of) the blue**: a sudden and unexpected event, a complete surprise.
>
> With reference to the unlikelihood of a thunderbolt coming from a
> clear blue sky.
>
> **1881** If Lydia had appeared in person it could hardly have given me a greater shock than this letter gave me. It was like a bolt from the
> blue.
> W. Westall, *Old Factory* vol. III. xii. 162
> [OED online]

---

> Thus seeing me in their midst when least expected, replaced the pain
> with abundant joy: the joy, likened to **a bolt from the blue.**
> [Yemi
> Prince; *The Birth of a Child in a Fishing Boat*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Hm-6CwAAQBAJ&pg=PA68&dq=%22a%20bolt%20from%20the%20blue%22%20happiness&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiYqPy_29KEAxXUD1kFHZCrAOU4ChDoAXoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=%22a%20bolt%20from%20the%20blue%22%20happiness&f=false) (2016)

> This unexpected utterance came like **a bolt from the blue** to
> Armance; never in all her life had she felt so happy.
> [Marie-Henri
> Beyle Stendhal; *Armance - Some Scenes from a Salon in Paris in
> 1827*](https://books.google.com/books?id=u8NmCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT72&dq=%22a%20bolt%20from%20the%20blue%22%20happiness&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj63afD3NKEAxXPFVkFHddCDVI4FBDoAXoECA0QAg#v=onepage&q=%22a%20bolt%20from%20the%20blue%22%20happiness&f=false)

> Been feeling blue because I had no luck trapping, nearly sick with
> worry, when like **a bolt from the blue** came good news and a check
> [Carol Fairbanks and Bergine Haakenson (eds.); *Writings of Farm Women,
> 1840-1940*](https://books.google.com/books?id=8EcrDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT277&dq=bolt%20from%20the%20blue%20good%20news&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiWmsuCtNOEAxV1EGIAHaN0BVkQ6AF6BAgNEAI#v=onepage&q=bolt%20from%20the%20blue%20good%20news&f=false) (2017)

Comment: I think this idiom carries negative connotations mostly. _Collins_, for example, defines the idiom thus: *a sudden, unexpected, and **usually unwelcome** event.*

Comment: @user405662 This [page](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bolt-from-the-blue) has three definitions; the one there you cite is credited to *Webster’s New World College Dictionary*. The other two definitions there, including the Collins, do not include a negative connotation; nor do almost all others I've checked. In any case, context will make the emotion clear, as the examples demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

**'Takes my breath away.'**

The expression 'takes my breath away' expresses that moment when one is left speechless and almost unable to take another breath.

It is noted since the 1800s, see below, Cambridge, but has been further made part of the English idiom by a famous song and associated film. Note that there is more than one song using the words.

---

> to be extremely beautiful or surprising:
> The beauty of the Taj Mahal took my breath away.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/take-breath-away)

> Astonish or shock one, with pleasure, surprise, or some other emotion. For example, That beautiful display just takes my breath away. This idiom alludes to the way one holds one's breath when overcome with sudden emotion. [Mid-1800s]

[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/take-one-s-breath-away)

> 'She takes my breath away'

[Wikipedia A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/She_Takes_My_Breath_Away)

> 'Take my breath away'

[Wikipedia B 'Top Gun'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Take_My_Breath_Away)